# Retrieving a table from database: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I want to retrieve a entire table from database and display it into my jsp page, but I am getting an error

my StaffBean. java is

```
package com.staff.bean;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


 public class StaffBean {

    private String date;
    private int workload;
    private int hourId;
    private int daysId;
    private int staffId;
    private String StaffName;
    private String ActiveORInactive;
    private String Stafftype;
    private String subcode;
    private boolean valid = false;

public String getdate() {
   // DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
 //   Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // your template here
    java.util.Date dateStr = null;
    try {
        dateStr = formatter.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    java.sql.Date dateDB = new java.sql.Date(dateStr.getTime());
    return formatter.format(dateDB);
}
public void setdate(String date){
    this.date=date;
}
public int gethourId() {
    return hourId;
}
public void sethourId(int hourId) {
    this.hourId = hourId;
}
public int getdaysId() {
    return daysId;
}
public void setdaysId(int daysId) {
    this.daysId = daysId;
}
public int getworkload() {
    return hourId;
}
public void setworkload(int workload) {
    this.workload = workload;
}
    public int getstaffId() {
        return staffId;
    }
    public void setstaffId(int staffId) {
        this.staffId = staffId;
    }
    public String getStaffName() {
        return StaffName;
    }
    public void setStaffName(String StaffName) {
        this.StaffName = StaffName;
    }
    public String ActiveORInactive() {
        return ActiveORInactive;
    }
    public void setActiveORInactive(String ActiveORInactive) {
        this.ActiveORInactive = ActiveORInactive;
    }

    public String getStafftype() {
        return Stafftype;
    }
    public void setStafftype(String Stafftype) {
        this.Stafftype = Stafftype;
    }
    public String getsubcode() {
        return Stafftype;
    }
    public void setsubcode(String subcode) {
        this.subcode = subcode;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return valid;
    }
    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
    }


}
```

and my GetAllDetailDAO.java is

```
 package com.staff.DAO;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

  import com.staff.bean.StaffBean;
  import com.staff.DB.ConnectionProvider;
  public class GetAllDetailDAO {

    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    private int noOfRecords;

    public List<StaffBean> viewAllStaff(int offSet, int noOfRecords){

        List<StaffBean> list = new ArrayList<StaffBean>();
        StaffBean _staffBean;
        try {
            con = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from  tblstaffdetails limit "+offSet+","+noOfRecords);
                    //+offSet+","+noOfRecords);
            //SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
            while(rs.next()){
                _staffBean = new StaffBean();
                _staffBean.setStaffName(rs.getString("StaffName"));
                _staffBean.setstaffId(rs.getInt("staffId"));
                _staffBean.setActiveORInactive(rs.getString("ActiveORInactive"));
                _staffBean.setStafftype(rs.getString("Stafftype"));
                list.add(_staffBean);
            }
            rs.close();          
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
            if(rs.next())
             this.noOfRecords = rs.getInt(1);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return list;

    }
    public int getNoOfRecords() {
      return noOfRecords;
    }
}
```

connection provider
      package com.staff.DB;

```
  import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionProvider {
    static Connection con;
    static String url;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        try{ 
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/StaffAllocation","root", "success");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf){
            cnf.printStackTrace();
        }

        return con;

    }

}
```

and my GetAllDetailServlet.java is

```
  package com.staff.servlet;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.sql.*;

  import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  import com.staff.bean.StaffBean;
  import com.staff.DAO.GetAllDetailDAO;
  import com.staff.DB.*;

  @WebServlet("/GetAllDetailServlet")
    public class GetAllDetailServlet extends HttpServlet{




/**
 * Servlet implementation class GetAllDetailsServlet
 */


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public GetAllDetailServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int page = 1;
        int recordsPerPage = 4;
        if(request.getParameter("page") != null)
            page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
            GetAllDetailDAO allDetailDAO = new GetAllDetailDAO();
            List<StaffBean> list  = allDetailDAO.viewAllStaff((page-1)*recordsPerPage, recordsPerPage);
        int noOfRecords = allDetailDAO.getNoOfRecords();
        int noOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(noOfRecords * 1.0 / recordsPerPage);
            request.setAttribute("staffList", list);
        request.setAttribute("noOfPages", noOfPages);
        request.setAttribute("currentPage", page);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/displayAllDetail.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);

        }
        }
```

and my DisplayAllDetail.jsp is

```
  <html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title> :: All Details</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <fieldset>
   <table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" align="center">
<tr>
<th>staffId</th>
    <th>StaffName</th>
    <th>ActiveORInactive</th>
    <th>Stafftype</th>
    <c:forEach var="_staffBean" items="${staffList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${_staffBean.staffId}</td>
            <td>${_staffBean.StaffName}</td>
            <td>${_staffBean.ActiveORInactive}</td>
            <td>${_staffBean.Stafftype}</td>        
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tr>
    </table>
    <c:if test="${currentPage != 1}">
<td><a href="getAll.do?method=get&page=${currentPage - 1}">Prev</a></td>
    </c:if>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" align="center">
<tr>
    <c:forEach begin="1" end="${noOfPages }" var="i">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${currentPage eq i }">
                <td>${i}</td>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <td><a href="getAll.do?method=get&page=${i}">${i}</a></td>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</tr>
</table>
<c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages }">
<td><a href="getAll.do?method=get&page=${currentPage+1 }">Next</a></td>
</c:if>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

my error is

```
  HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/displayAllDetail.jsp at line 22
  type Exception report

  message An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/displayAllDetail.jsp at line 22

  description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

  exception 

  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/displayAllDetail.jsp at line 22

19:         <c:forEach var="_staffBean" items="${staffList}">
20:             <tr>
21:                 <td>${_staffBean.staffId}</td>
22:                 <td>${_staffBean.StaffName}</td>
23:                 <td>${_staffBean.ActiveORInactive}</td>
24:                 <td>${_staffBean.Stafftype}</td>        
25:             </tr>
```

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    com.staff.servlet.GetAllDetailServlet.doGet(GetAllDetailServlet.java:56)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

```
    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'StaffName' not found on type   com.staff.bean.StaffBean
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:237)
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:214)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:325)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
org.apache.jsp.jsp.displayAllDetail_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(displayAllDetail_jsp.java:157)
org.apache.jsp.jsp.displayAllDetail_jsp._jspService(displayAllDetail_jsp.java:99)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
com.staff.servlet.GetAllDetailServlet.doGet(GetAllDetailServlet.java:56)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.

Comment: Do not ask for help in the title - everybody who asks a question here wants answers.

Comment: In getdate(), you are parsing a date string into a Date, and then formatting it back to a String again???? I really don't think you want to do that!

Comment: NickJ, please help me with my error. i want to retrieve a table and display it, can u help with that?

Comment: Please update your question with the code changes you have made. I can't see anything else wrong.

Comment: i have not made much changes. the only thing is that the table is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Try to declare

```
    private String staffName;
    private String activeORInactive;
    private String stafftype;
```

And not with capital letters.

I suggest you to follow the [Java Code convertions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: but i have created name of the column starting with capitals.. bt what change will that make if i edit these to smaller case?

Comment: How are you mapping your db? Are you using OpenJpa, Hibernate?? How do you initialize ConnectionProvider?

Comment: i am sorry.. i will include my connection provider to my question now

Comment: I assume your are using Hibernate. The JavaObject property name and the column name has nothing to do with each other. Only the mapping you are using (that is mainly the porpuse of Hibernate, to make you forget about db names and only work with an object oriented programming)
In your java object you should follow the conventions and js will not have problems

Comment: If you beginner in programming, and you are using Hibernate, I would string discourage you. Hibernate is only suitable for advanced programmers. I would suggest you learn JDBC instead.

Comment: i dont use hibernate. i will try what you said

Comment: @NickJ using Hibernate, or any other JPA implementation requires a deep knowledge in what you are doing, you are completely right. But only reading, trying and working with it is the way to eventually learn it (The same with JDBC)

Answer (score 0):

Further to Blanca Hdez's correct answer, change the JSP so the case of staffName is correct:

```
<td>${_staffBean.StaffName}</td>
```

should be:

```
<td>${_staffBean.staffName}</td>
```

Note the lowercase 's' for 'staffName' - very important!

Comment: Did you also do Blanca Hdez's suggestion?

Comment: yes. i tried converting into small case letters. please check my jsp page. the error is on the line stating c:forEach var="_staffBean" items="${staffList}"

Comment: what value should be given to var? what must be replaced with _staffBean